# java null pointer exception when trying to show image using path from database

Tags: android

I am working on a contact list project and the last thing i need to do is display images for each of my contact.
In code from below i want to show my image by using the path wich is saved in my edittext1:
but i get NUll pointer exception on this  line:

```
 String username = mpic.getText().toString(); 



        private void ShowImage()
  {
      //string username created from edit text field to a string
      EditText mpic =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
      String username = mpic.getText().toString(); 
        //bitmap will decode the string to a image (bitmap)
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(username);
        //Image view used to set the bitmap
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        //setting the image to the image view
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

  }
```

The whole class is :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main); 
     ShowImage();
      showDatabaseContent();
      lv1 = getListView();

      lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

       lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
           cursor = (Cursor) a.getItemAtPosition(position);
           itemId = cursor.getString(6);
           openOptionsMenu();
           }
       });

       lv1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

       });
   }

   //selected item index from ListView
   public void showDialogItemId(long itemId){
       Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected index is" + Long.toString(itemId), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
       switch (item.getItemId()){
           case R.id.modifyitem:
               if(null != itemId){
                   Bundle contactToModify = new Bundle();
                   contactToModify.putString("cFirstName", cursor.getString(0));
                   contactToModify.putString("cMobilePhone", cursor.getString(5));
                   contactToModify.putString("cEmail", cursor.getString(2));
                   contactToModify.putString("curl", cursor.getString(3));
                   contactToModify.putString("cAdress", cursor.getString(4));
                  contactToModify.putString ("cphoto", cursor.getString(1));
                   contactToModify.putString("mod_type", "modifyPerson");
                   Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactDetails.class);
                   intent.setClass(this, ContactDetails.class);
                   intent.putExtras(contactToModify);
                   startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_MODIFIED);
               }else{
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Select Contact to modify", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               break;
           case R.id.additem:

               Intent i = new Intent(this, ContactDetails.class);
               Bundle bun = new Bundle();
               bun.putString("mod_type", "addPerson");
               i.setClass(this, ContactDetails.class);
               i.putExtras(bun);
               startActivityForResult(i, CONTACT_ADDED);
               break;

           case R.id.removeitem:
               if(null != itemId){
                   removeContact(itemId);
                   showDatabaseContent();
               }
               else{
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Select Contact to delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               break;
           case R.id.search:
               Intent j =new Intent(this,Search.class);
               j.setClass(this, Search.class);
               startActivity(j);
                break;

       }
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
       // See which child activity is calling us back.
       switch (resultCode) {
           case CONTACT_ADDED:
               // This is the standard resultCode that is sent back if the
               // activity crashed or didn't doesn't supply an explicit result.
               if (resultCode == RESULT_FIRST_USER){
                   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                   bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("contactData");
                   addContact(bundle);
                   showDatabaseContent();
               } 
               else{
                   Toast.makeText(this, "CANCEL CONTACT BUTTON PRESSED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               break;
           case CONTACT_MODIFIED:
               if (resultCode == 2){
                   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                   bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("contactData");
                   modifyContact(bundle);
                   showDatabaseContent();
               }
               else{
                   Toast.makeText(this, "MODIFY CONTACT FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               break;
           default:
               break;
       }
   }

 //method removes item from database
   private void removeContact(String itemId){
       db = contacts.getWritableDatabase();
       db.delete(DbConstants.TABLE_NAME, "_ID=" + itemId, null);

   }

   private void addContact(Bundle bundle) {
          // Insert a new record into the Events data source.
          // You would do something similar for delete and update.
          db = contacts.getWritableDatabase();
          ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
          vals.put(DbConstants.NAME, bundle.getString("contactFirstName"));
          vals.put(DbConstants.PHONE, bundle.getString("contactMobilePhone"));
          vals.put(DbConstants.EMAIL, bundle.getString("contactEmail"));
          vals.put(DbConstants.URL_STRING,bundle.getString("contactUrl"));
          vals.put(DbConstants.ADRESS,bundle.getString("contactadress"));
          vals.put(DbConstants.PHOTO,bundle.getString("contactphoto"));
          db.insertOrThrow(DbConstants.TABLE_NAME, null, vals);
       }

 //method should modify existing Contact
   private void modifyContact(Bundle bundle){
       db = contacts.getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
       vals.put(DbConstants.NAME, bundle.getString("contactFirstName"));
       vals.put(DbConstants.PHONE, bundle.getString("contactMobilePhone"));
       vals.put(DbConstants.EMAIL, bundle.getString("contactEmail"));
       vals.put(DbConstants.URL_STRING,bundle.getString("contactUrl"));
    vals.put(DbConstants.ADRESS,bundle.getString("contactadress"));
    vals.put(DbConstants.PHOTO,bundle.getString("contactphoto"));
       db.update(DbConstants.TABLE_NAME, vals, _ID+"="+itemId, null);
   }

   private Cursor getContacts() {
          db = contacts.getReadableDatabase();
          cursor = db.query(DbConstants.TABLE_NAME, FROM, null, null, null,
                null, null);
          startManagingCursor(cursor);
          return cursor;
   }

   public void showDatabaseContent(){
       contacts = new DbCreate(this); 
       try {
           cursor = getContacts(); 
           showContacts(cursor); 
       } finally {
           contacts.close();
           db.close();

       }
   }


   private void showContacts(Cursor cursor) {
       //set up data binding
       SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, FROM, TO);
       setListAdapter(adapter);
   }
  private void ShowImage()
  {
      //string username created from edit text field to a string
      EditText mpic =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
      String username = mpic.getText().toString(); 
        //bitmap will decode the string to a image (bitmap)
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(username);
        //Image view used to set the bitmap
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        //setting the image to the image view
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

  }
```

Whole error:

```
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.dbcontactconsole/org.example.dbcontactconsole.DbContactConsole}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at org.example.dbcontactconsole.DbContactConsole.ShowImage(DbContactConsole.java:234)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at org.example.dbcontactconsole.DbContactConsole.onCreate(DbContactConsole.java:46)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
 12-30 20:33:23.292: E/AndroidRuntime(4297): ... 11 more
```

Comment: String username = mpic.getText().toString(); first line

Answer (score 1):

can you post your main.xml layout file?  I would guess the

```
findViewById(R.id.edittext1)
```

call is returning null, perhaps because of some misidentification issue...

Answer (score 0):

check to see if the mpic returns null.  Maybe the id name is incorrect?  Maybe you need to call the findViewById method on the correct view for instance

```
EditText mpic =(EditText)myView.findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
```